# Intellij, Thymeleaf, recognise instanceof during code inspection

Tags: intellij-idea, code-inspection

I was wondering if it was possible to have Intellij code inspection recognise "instanceof" and mark it as correct. 
The code i provided in the picture works, I just want to stop Intellij from drawing the red line

[Picture of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMMjM.png)

Comment: Please edit your question. Before that, read the rules of this community and welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ignore and supress inspections for Intellij from the Settings menu.

*Settings/Preferences dialog (Ctrl+Alt+S), select Editor | Inspections.*

Or you can supress/disable inspections by selecting the statement and pressing `Alt + Enter` and then pressing `Disable inspection` (if this is provided) . You can read the official [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html) from Intellij.

You can find the full list of Java inspections for Intellij [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/list-of-java-inspections.html).

Comment: I would prefer to leave the code inspection on and instead have intellij recognise the instanceof operator wiwthin the html file